# ConstructorArguments without magic strings

Tags: ninject

If I want to specify a constructor argument I need to specify the argument name as string. Unfortunately, this is not very refactoring friendly. Is there any way to get around this limitation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constructor Argument Enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607171/constructor-argument-enums)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/05/28/ninject-constructor-selection-preview/ . The next release of Ninject will support to type safely define constructor arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
string s = "my string"
kernel.Bind<IMyInterface>().ToConstructor(x => new MyObject(s));
```

where MyObject implements IMyInterface.